# Create a view based on three different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I have a table called Ingredients, with the following fields:

**Ingredients** - IngredientID (PK), ManufacturerID (FK), CategoryID (FK), BarcodeID (FK), SizeID (FK), Quality.

The way this table works is like this: each ingredient is going to be based on EITHER manufacturer, category, or barcode, **only one of the three, and one is always required**. So if a record has a ManufacturerID, CategoryID and BarcodeID will both be null, and vice-versa.

There are three other tables in my database:

**Manufacturers** - ManufacturerID (PK), Name

**Categories** - CategoryID (PK), Name

**Barcodes** - BarcodeID (PK), Name

I need a view that looks like this:

**View** - ViewID (PK), IngredientID (FK), Name, SizeID, Quality

Where **ViewID** will be the PK,
**IngredientID** will be the FK to the ingredient record,
**Name** will be the Name field coming from either the Manufacturers, Categories, or Barcodes table based on which of the three fields had a value in the Ingredients table, 
and **SizeID** and **Quality** will come directly from the Ingredients table.

My knowledge of SQL is very limited and I would appreciate any guidance. Please let me know if my description of the problem lacks any vital information.

Edit: Updated the view to include the FK IngredientID, which could be useful.

Comment: I don't think you can create PK in views, and for other data go through [JOINS tutorial here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) and make an attempt to write query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work using a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT I.IngredientID, 
   CASE 
      WHEN I.ManufacturerID IS NOT NULL THEN M.Name 
      WHEN I.CategoryID  IS NOT NULL THEN C.Name 
      WHEN I.BarcodeID IS NOT NULL THEN B.Name 
   END Name,
   I.SizeID,
   I.Quality
FROM Ingredients I
   LEFT JOIN Manufacturers M ON I.ManufacturerId = M.ManufacturerId
   LEFT JOIN Categories C ON I.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
   LEFT JOIN Barcodes B ON I.BarcodeID = B.BarcodeID
```

This uses the IngredientId as your Primary Key -- which is what I assumed you wanted.  There is no need for another Primary Key.  If you really just want an incremental Id, then use ROW_NUMBER -- but I don't see why it would be needed:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY I.IngredientID), ...
```

Comment: Works great. I didn't know you could do a CASE in SQL, and this is a much simpler solution that I thought would be. Thanks!

Comment: @etc2702 -- no problem, glad we could help!  There are other approaches using ISNULL or COALESCE, but this is perhaps the most readable to understand.  Best of luck.

Comment: Coalesce might be faster - replace the CASE with "COALESCE(M.Name, C.Name, B.Name".

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  i.IngredientID as ViewID, 
  isnull(m.Name, isnull(c.Name, isnull(b.Name, ''))) as Name
  i.SizeID,
  i.Quality
from Ingredients i
  left join Manufacturers m on i.ManufacturerID = m.ManufacturerID 
  left join Categories c on i.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
  left join Barcodes b on i.BarcodeID = b.BarcodeID
```